# Literal converstion NSData to NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata

I am new to iOS programming and i am trying to get a textual representation of an NSData object as a NSString

For example if the NSData object is:

```
<07010013 01020000 09000100 000199c2>
```

I want to convert that to:

```
"070100130102000009000100000199c2"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: pls query SO before askin'  it is a huge knowledge-base you will find answer while you can learn

Comment: "NSData", "NSString", "hex" will be 3 useful keywords when searching for this

Comment: Thank you for editing my post and for the mature comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT#1**  //*general answer*

`NSString` provides an initializer for this purpose. You can see [more info using the docs here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData%3aencoding%3a)

```
NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mynsdata 
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Assuming you use ARC.

**HINT#2** // *the answer for hex nsdata*

```
int len = [mynsdata length];
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len*2];
const unsigned char *nsdata_bytes = [mynsdata bytes];
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    [str appendFormat:@"%02x", nsdata_bytes[i]];
}
```