# How to convert Hexadecimal NSData to Decimal array?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an array with hexadecimal value like below:

```
const UInt8 request_MifareID[] = {
        0x00, 0xCA, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x00
    };
```

then i transfer it to NSData for communication:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(UInt8 *)request_MifareID length:5];
```

Sent "data" to server and get the server response:

```
Printing description of resp:
<ee97562d 02280400 00000000 21074400 9000>

NSUInteger len = [resp length];

Printing description of len:
(NSUInteger) len = 18
```

the "resp" is also a Hexadecimal format NSData

now, i have to transfer the "resp" to Decimal array

how should i do?

------------------------------------------------------Edit

Ok, first

i have to transfer the NSData which server response(it is not String, just numbers):

```
ee97562d 02280400 00000000 21074400 9000
```

into what kind of object?

Byte?

when i use

```
NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: resp
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

it returns nil

Comment: The representation in memory is not "decimal" or "hexadecimal". It doesn't depend on how you format it. Do `NSLog(@"%u", ((uint8_t *)[data bytes])[0])`, and voilà.

Comment: Please see another SO thread on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066246/literal-converstion-nsdata-to-nsstring/19066281#19066281

Comment: Yes, the data is not "hexadecimal".  It is merely being displayed in hexadecimal format for your convenience.

Comment: When you do the NSString initWitData you get a nil result because the contents of the NSData object is not legal UTF8 character code data.

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = 0xe; // or 0x3, 0x6, 0x8, 0x2

NSString * decimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
NSString * hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", number];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:"FF3C" length:4];
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
string = [@"0x" stringByAppendingString:string];

unsigned short value;
sscanf([string UTF8String], "%hx", &value);

NSLog(@"%d", value)**
```

Comment: string will return nil